# Как загрузить картинку в личное сообщение в vk (бот)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

В python был сгенерирована картинка. Точнее был сделан график. Нужно этот график отправить ботом в личном сообщении в vk. Как это сделать, не скачивая картинки на компьютер?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какой тип авторизации и какие ключи Вы используете для работы с API. Или же детализируйте вопрос, чтобы можно было привести конкретную часть кода, а не решение целиком.

Comment: я получаю график plt. В документации Vk написано что нужна ссылка на картинку. Я не хочу скачивать картинку на комп, а сразу передавать её в скрипт

Comment: В любом случае Вам придётся сохранить Ваш график в файл (`plt.savefig('file.png')`) и загрузить его на сервер ВК. После загрузки на сервер, Вы можете удалять файл с компьютера.

Answer (score 1):

[io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) - позволяет работать с потоком байт *в памяти* как с объектом типа `file` в Python:

```
import io

# ....

buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то делал отправку скриншота в личку. Я думаю если ты сохранишь файл то сможешь отправить

id - это кому отправить
my_id - твой id

```
data = vkapi.photos.getMessagesUploadServer(peer_id = id, v = '5.85')
url = data['upload_url']
img = {'photo': ('file.png', open(r'file.png', 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files = img)
r = json.loads(r.text)
server = r['server']
photo = r['photo']
hash = r['hash']
photo_id = vkapi.photos.saveMessagesPhoto(server = server, photo = photo, hash = hash, v = '5.85')
photo_id = photo_id[0]['id']
vkapi.messages.send(v = '5.85', peer_id = id, attachment = 'photo' + str(my_id) + '_' + str(photo_id))
```

Единственная проблема может возникнуть в том, что API могли обновить, а я прогу не обновлял.